# Write MPI program : sum in a the array with two process

Tags: c++, c, mpi

i want to write a program with mpi.h  this program do To sum the numbers in an array

for example i have one array a[10] with this numbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 and i want sum=1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10= 55

this should work with to process ?

how can do it ?

Comment: Be more specific. Is this a parallel programming exercise? What is mpi.h?

Comment: @Osiris see the mpi tag.

Comment: You can do it by first writing a non-MPI program to sum an array and then consider how to divide the work over N processes.  Then you could come back here and ask for help but also be able to demonstrate, as your current question fails lamentably to do, that you have made a serious effort to tackle your own problem.  And to the experts reading this: yes, I know that (for an expert) first writing a sequential program and later parallelising it may not be an optimal strategy but it is a sound pedagogical strategy for a complete beginner.

Answer (score 3):

```
MPI_init(&argc,&argv);


int size;
int myrank;
int sum=0;
int chunksize =10/2; //This is arraysize divided by total number of processes
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_Comm_world,&myrank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_Comm_world,&size)


int lower=myrank*chunksize;
int upper=lower+chunksize;
for(int i=lower;i<upper;i++)
{
sum=sum+a[lower];

}
if(myrank==0)
{
MPI_Send(....,sum,1) // see the exact syntax of this routine.I am doing is process 0 is sending its sum to process 1
}
else
{
MPI_recv(....,recvsum,0,..)

sum=sum+recvsum;
printf("The sum is %d",sum);
}


set the np parameter to 2 while compiling
```

Comment: Do you mean `sum += a[i];` instead of `sum += a[lower];`? And you might want to end that `printf()` with a `'\n'`.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://users.abo.fi/mats/PP2012/examples/MPI/send-standard.c) example on sending and receiving using MPI.

```
int wpp = n/np;
for(i=wpp * me; i < wpp * (me+1); ++i){
   partialSum += a[i];
}
```

Make me==1 send to process with me==0.